# How to grant MySQL server administration privileges (SUPER, RELOAD...) with ansible?

Tags: mysql, ansible

Is there a way how to grant MySQL administration privileges using Ansible mysql_user module (or using any other module)? I want to set `SUPER`, `RELOAD` and `SHOW DATABASES` privileges to the user along with some other database-specific privs.

Following *basic* setup works well for me:

```
- name: Set user privileges
  mysql_user:
    user={{ mysql_user }}
    password={{ mysql_password }}
    state=present
    priv={{ item }}
  with_items:
    - 'somedatabase.*:ALL'
    - 'someotherdatabase.*:ALL'
```

...results in:

```
TASK: [db | Set user privileges]
**********************************************
ok: [dbuser] => (item=somedatabase.*:ALL)
ok: [dbuser] => (item=someotherdatabase.*:ALL)
```

---

Following setup keeps saying "changed" and the privileges are not what one would expect:

```
- name: Set user privileges
  mysql_user:
    user={{ mysql_user }}
    password={{ mysql_password }}
    state=present
    priv={{ item }}
  with_items:
    - '*.*:SUPER,RELOAD,SHOW\ DATABASES'
    - 'somedatabase.*:ALL'
    - 'someotherdatabase.*:ALL'
```

(repeated) run:

```
TASK: [db | Set user privileges]
**********************************************
changed: [dbuser] => (item=*.*:SUPER,RELOAD,SHOW\ DATABASES)
changed: [dbuser] => (item=somedatabase.*:ALL)
ok: [dbuser] => (item=someotherdatabase.*:ALL)
```

results in:

```
mysql> show grants for 'dbuser'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for dbuser@localhost                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'dbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2046D2DDAE359F311435E8B4D3776EFE13FB584C' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `somedatabase`.* TO 'dbuser'@'localhost'                                              |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `someotherdatabase`.* TO 'dbuser'@'localhost'                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does anyone know how to:

1. set `SUPER`, `RELOAD` and `SHOW DATABASE` admin. privileges?
2. make the configuration idempotent?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found out the elegant solution after all! First of all the privileges should be defined somewhere as a list:

```
$ cat group_vars/dbservers
mysql_privileges:
  - 'somedatabase.*:ALL'
  - 'someotherdatabase.*:ALL'
  - '*.*:SUPER,RELOAD,SHOW\ DATABASES'
```

then the `mysql_user` plugin does not need to *append* the privileges, simply use the privileges string mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/mysql_user_module.html) in following format: `mydb.*:INSERT,UPDATE/anotherdb.*:SELECT/yetanotherdb.*:ALL`.

The only trick is how to convert list to the string:

```
- name: Set user privileges
  mysql_user:
    user={{ mysql_user }}
    password={{ mysql_password }}
    state=present
    priv={{ mysql_privileges|join('/') }}
```

The repeatable run of the task does not say *changed* anymore:

```
TASK: [db | Set user privileges]
**********************************************
ok: [dbuser]
```

Answer (score 8):

Found out that when switched the order of the privileges I am able to grant mentioned admin. privileges:

```
- name: Set user privileges
  mysql_user:
    user={{ mysql_user }}
    password={{ mysql_password }}
    state=present
    append_privs=yes
    priv={{ item }}
  with_items:
    - 'somedatabase.*:ALL'
    - 'someotherdatabase.*:ALL'
    - '*.*:SUPER,RELOAD,SHOW\ DATABASES'
```

privileges are set as expected:

```
mysql> show grants for 'dbuser'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for dbuser@localhost                                                                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT RELOAD, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER ON *.* TO 'dbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2046D2DDAE359F311435E8B4D3776EFE13FB584C' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `somedatabase`.* TO 'dbuser'@'localhost'                                                                      |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `someotherdatabase`.* TO 'dbuser'@'localhost'                                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

though the task is still not idempotent. Every run gives me:

```
TASK: [db | Set user privileges]
**********************************************
changed: [dbuser] => (item=somedatabase.*:ALL)
ok: [dbuser] => (item=someotherdatabase.*:ALL)
changed: [dbuser] => (item=*.*:SUPER,RELOAD,SHOW\ DATABASES)
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `append_privs`

Answer (score 5):

There's no need for tricks with lists, you can set multiple privileges separated by a slash:

```
- name: Set user privileges
  mysql_user:
    user: {{ mysql_user }}
    password: {{ mysql_password }}
    state: present
    priv: 'somedatabase.*:ALL/someotherdatabase.*:ALL/*.*:SUPER,RELOAD,SHOW DATABASES'
```

or shorter:

```
- name: Set user privileges
  mysql_user: user={{ mysql_user }} 
  password={{ mysql_password }} 
  state=present
   priv='somedatabase.*:ALL/someotherdatabase.*:ALL/*.*:SUPER,RELOAD,SHOW DATABASES'
```

Comment: This definitely can be one of the use-cases, but I needed to grant a list of privileges for some databases and a super-set of privileges for some other databases. Your approach would lead to repetition of those "shared" privileges. Though your solution is good enough for simpler cases ;) Thanks for the answer!